# Is it possible to change the minimum ada value for an UTxO?

Tags: nft, ada, utxo, eutxo, minadatxout

If I want to send a token or NFT in Cardano, I need to include some ada with it. This is known as `minimum-ada-value`.

Is it possible to change this value for a specific NFT and make it so big that it is almost impossible to send the NFT?

I'm thinking of this solution as a way of implementing non-transferable tokens in Cardano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minAda requirement is given by the protocol parameters and is a core parameter that cannot be changed for individual UTxOs.

If you want to create non-transferable tokens on Cardano, please check out this thread, this was just answered recently :).

[Non-transferrable Tokens](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/8792/5085)